# What is the proper way to cache a user profile in the MVC5 layout page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a UserProfile class which is generated and updated for each new registered user. What is the proper technique for storing/caching that object in the layout page so it can be used every time a new page loads once the user has logged in and is authenticated?

I currently am loading it into a model

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var lvm = new LayoutViewModel { AppUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId() };
            lvm.LoggedInUserProfile =
                MyProject.UserService.UserHelpers.GetProfileForLoggedInUser(lvm.AppUserId);

            var iconSource = string.Empty; //= ConfigurationHelpers.UserIcons.FemaleUserIconSource;//var profile = MyProject.UserService.UserHelpers.GetUserProfileIncluding(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            if (lvm.LoggedInUserProfile != null)
            {
                if (lvm.LoggedInUserProfile.AvatarUrl != null)
                {
                    iconSource = lvm.LoggedInUserProfile.Gender == Gender.Female ? ConfigurationHelpers.UserIcons.FemaleUserIconSource : ConfigurationHelpers.UserIcons.MaleUserIconSource;
                }
                iconSource = lvm.LoggedInUserProfile.AvatarUrl;
            }

            if (lvm.LoggedInUserProfile != null) ViewData.Add("FullName", lvm.LoggedInUserProfile.FirstName);
            ViewData.Add("IconSource", iconSource);
            ViewData.Add("ViewModel", lvm);
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```

but this seems to run dozens of times and seems wasteful.

Comment: You can try session

Comment: @codelover...in MVC5? I thought that was a webforms thing

Comment: @dinotom Session is there in MVC too.

Comment: @codelover - Session is [not recommended for user profile data](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/).

Comment: @NightOwl888...why not? most answers from googling that show Session as valid usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Session, as suggested by the two commenters, seems to be the way to go. Now that code is only being hit once.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Session["LayoutViewModel"] == null)
        {
            var lvm = new LayoutViewModel { AppUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId() };
            lvm.LoggedInUserProfile =
                MyProject.Services.UserService.UserHelpers.GetProfileForLoggedInUser(lvm.AppUserId);

            if (lvm.LoggedInUserProfile != null)
            {
                Session["LayoutViewModel"] = lvm;
            }
            else
            {
                Session["LayoutViewModel"] = null;
            }

        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```

And in your layout view, make sure you cast the Session when retrieving it.

```
@using MyProject.ViewModels
@{
    var svm = (LayoutViewModel)Session["LayoutViewModel"];
 }
```